# Video in JPanel is not showing at a side

Tags: java, maven, swing

I am trying to build a JFrame where a video will keep playing at one side of the screen and the login feature will be on the other side. I want to play the vide at any side, but it just keeps coming to the center of the screen. Here is the code :

```
package Inventory;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;

public class LoginPage extends JFrame {

    MediaPlayerFactory factory;
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer player;
    JPanel videoPanel = new JPanel();

    LoginPage() {

        this.setTitle("Inventory Management System");
        this.setSize(1200,800);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        player = factory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        player.videoSurface().set(factory.videoSurfaces().newVideoSurface(canvas));

        videoPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        videoPanel.add(canvas);

        this.setContentPane(videoPanel);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                play();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                stop();
            }
        });

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void play() {

        if(player.status().isPlaying()) {
            player.controls().stop();
        }

        player.media().play("FlowCount.mp4");

    }

    public void stop() {

        player.controls().stop();
        player.release();
        factory.release();

    }
}
```

I want it on the left side of the screen. I have looked here and there but could not find anything.

Comment: *but it just keeps coming to the center of the screen* - you don't specify where in the BorderLayout the video should be displayed. The default is the CENTER. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Comment: Just beware that mixing heavy weight (`Canvas`) and light weight (Swing components, like `JPanel`) don't always play nice